# get chrome.runtime in NW.js

Tags: google-chrome-app, nw.js

I'm trying to port a Chrome app to a NW.js one. This is my first time doing anything with NW.js, but I read this: http://nwjs.io/blog/chrome-apps-support/ and I'm following the steps trying to convert this [Analytics app](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/analytics). My problem is that `chrome.runtime` is `undefined` in the NW.js app. Any ideas?

Comment: How do you convert it? NW.js runs this app directly as is.

Comment: @wOxxOm I was getting this problem when dragging the folder to the NW executable. When I packaged it, it worked fine.

Comment: Weird, I can drag'n'drop it fine here...

Comment: @wOxxOm I can drag and drop fine too. But after the drop if I do `chrome.runtime` from the console I'm getting `undefined`

Comment: I've tried on nw.js v0.17.4 and chrome.runtime is displayed properly both in main window and the background page.

Comment: @wOxxOm after dropping the analytics app for example?

Comment: Yes. I would be surprised if nw.js couldn't handle drag'n'drop properly. It would be a major bug.

Comment: @wOxxOm hmm, I don't know then :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting this problem when dragging the folder to the NW executable. When I packaged it, it worked fine.

Comment: You should report this as a bug; also, it would be great if you tested if the shell command to launch it with the folder path is working or not.